# Recommended reading for (Object Oriented) application design architecture?

Tags: object-oriented, application-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best books on the theory and practice of software architecture?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22146/best-books-on-the-theory-and-practice-of-software-architecture)

In life it doesnt matter if you do one thing for 15 years. You **will** end up waking one day and asking stuff that are equal to  "how do i walk?" :)

My specific question is that as a new entrant to C# and OOP i am stepping into many little "details" that need to be addressed.

Written a lot of code in VB.NET / cobol / simple php e.t.c surely does not help much into the OOP world...

So , even after reading entry level books for C# and watching some videos i recently found out about the "factory model design" for applications.

I would appreciate if any of you guys recomment some reading on application design architecture for further reading...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- **Object Oriented Design:**
  [Object-Oriented Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136300707)
  Is one of my favorite books on the topic, a bit dense, but otherwise
  great. Average of 4.5 Star Reviews.
- **Object-Oriented Thought Process, The (3rd Edition):**
  [Object-Oriented Thought Process, The (3rd Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672330164). Is a more recently released option…also very good.
- **Python 3 Object Oriented Programming:**
  [Python 3 Object Oriented Programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849511268)

Answer (score 23):

[SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) is a very good starting point. These are the 5 basic principles of object oriented design, which state what follows:

1. **Single responsibility principle**: your objects (classes) should have *single responsibility*. In other words, there should be only one reason to change given entity/class.
2. **Open/Closed principle**: classes should be *open for extension, closed for modification*. Classes itselves shouldn't change much, yet they should *provide extension points* so their behavior can be altered/expanded by future implementators.
3. **Liskov substitution principle**: each object should be replacable by its more specific subtype without altering correctness of program. As in, if something works with `Mammal` type, it should work just as good with `Tiger` and `Panda` types.
4. **Interface segregation principle**: by Wiki "many client specific interfaces are better than one general purpose interface". This goes in pair with SRP and decoupled design - you should prefer *multiple task-specific* entities instead of *single general-purpose* one.
5. **Dependency inversion principle**: you should design by contract, not by concrete implementation. Which often narrows down to having *contracts* (interfaces) passed arround as dependencies instead of their implementations (classes).

Reading up on those topics should probably spawn new questions and lead you to further research. Which should probably include (among others) following important concepts:

- [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)
- [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), IoC containers
- design for testability, [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)